# Новый перевод через API yandex Translate

Tags: php, яндекс-переводчик

Я, конечно, дилетант в этом вопросе, но до конца не могу понять, как реализуется в коде php подключение к yandex translate через API-ключ. Как правильно это реализовывать, ведь в документации ничего об этом не сказано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы действительно не дошли до третьей страницы документации?

[image: Imgur]

```
$key = 'aaaabbbbccccdddd';
$url = sprintf('https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs?key=%s&ui=ru', $key);
$data = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: <?php
$key = 'trnsl.1.1.20141019T052112Z.fba5ee2ce80ee96e.e1307571361be995350710c5d9f497e47ac259d7';
$url = sprintf('https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs?key=%s&ui=ru', $key);
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$text = "Hello world";
$lang = 'en ru';

?>

А дальше то что? Как перевести?

Comment: @ggLike, воспользоваться методами, описанными на [пятой странице документации](https://api.yandex.ru/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate.xml)

    $params = array(
        'key' => $key,
        'lang' => 'en-ru',
        'text' => 'Hello world',
    );
    $query = http_build_query($params);
    $response = file_get_contents('https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?' . $query);
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    $text = $data['text'][0];

Comment: я повторно перечитал API но так и не понял до конца как работает Yandex translate пробовал вашим методом выводит текст на английском!

Comment: @ggLike, хм, он почему-то hello world не переводит. 'Can i borrow your moustache?' - на ура.

Comment: @Etki я вам отписал, что вы ответили на вопрос. Большое спасибо! Выше в комментариях я написал, почему не работал перевод.
Кстати, действительно программисты в яндексе с юмором, раз решили закрыть перевод 'Hello World'. XD